# OmniAuth Registration test failing, login passes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, rspec, omniauth

I'm trying to allow a user to register with my app via Twitter using OmniAuth, and am getting some seemingly strange behavior. If I create a User model first, then generate an authentication hash to send to my method to create or return a user from the database, it works great. If I do not create a User model first, the hash I send to the same method gives an error "undefined method 'provider' for #". I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...

Here is my user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it "should have a name" do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    should respond_to(:name)
  end

  it "should allow registration via twitter" do
        auth = {
        :provider => "twitter",
        :uid => '1234567',
        :info => {
            :nickname => 'NewUser'
        }
    }
        tested_user = User.process_omniauth(auth)
        expect(tested_user.persisted?).to be_false
    end

  it "should allow login via twitter" do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    auth = {
        :provider => "twitter",
        :uid => '1234567',
        :info => {
            :nickname => 'NewUser'
        }
    }
    tested_user = User.process_omniauth(auth)
    expect(tested_user).to eq(@user)
    end

end
```

Here is my factory users.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'NewUser'
    email 'test@test.com'
    password 'testing'
    password_confirmation 'testing'
    home_dropzone 'New Dropzone'
    bio "Here's a short description about things"
    provider 'twitter'
    uid '1234567'
  end
end
```

Here is my User.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :jumps

  validates :name, presence: true

  def self.process_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.nickname
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session['devise.user_attributes']
        new(session['devise.user_attributes'], without_protection: true) do |user|
            user.attributes = params
            user.valid?
        end
    else
        super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    if encrypted_password.blank? && provider.present?
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

And my output from rspec is as follows:

```
Failures:

1) User should allow registration via twitter
Failure/Error: tested_user = User.process_omniauth(auth)
NoMethodError:
   undefined method 'provider' for #<Hash:0xb2348ac>
# ./app/models/user.rb:13:in 'block in process_omniauth'
# ./app/models/user.rb:12:in 'process_omniauth'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not sure why it's not allowing me to access the hash that I passed into my User process_omniauth method. If anyone can help explain why it's not letting me access the key, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes don't remap their keys to functions.

```
a = { foo: :bar, baz: :qux }
```

I am not allowed to use

```
a.foo
```

However, I am able to do

```
a[:foo]
```

So, in your `User` model, just change your `auth.key` calls with `auth[:key]`.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue. I'm still not sure why I was able to access the values via auth.provider, auth.uid, etc during my "should allow login via twitter" test and not the other one, but this causes both to pass. When I call .first_or_create, and it finds an item (such as when my User factory creates an object), does auth then become something besides a hash that has these functions available?

Comment: You most likely had some form of object, which is why you were able to do that.